# How to handle multiple .env files on Vercel?

Tags: git, next.js, vercel

In my private git repository, I have 3 env files for every environment

```
.env.local

.env.development

.env.production
```

My production branch is `main` and the preview environment (staging or pre-production) branch is `development`. When I push changes to the `development` branch, Vercel is reading the `.env.production` file instead of the `.env.development`

How can I make Vercel read a specific env file for a specific environment? In the NextJS documentation says we can have those multiple env files

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the path for what you are calling.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#path

example:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` })
```